# jqgrid check box selection issue

Tags: jqgrid

i am using jqgrid version 3.6. I enabled the check box functionality using "multiselect: true". It is working fine but the problem is ,

If selects any row it unselects the previously selected checkboxes.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by using the "beforeSelectRow()" event

```
beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e){
    $jquery("#hwpoGridview").jqGrid('setSelection',rowid);
  }
```